# Where do you put the inverter? Near the battery or near the load?

Tags: ac, dc, solar-cell

Where do you put the inverter to minimize power loss on a stand alone solar setup?

I'm using DC 12V as power on devices but I notice resistance on wires when running long lengths. AC is better on long distance, so I was thinking of converting to AC then just convert again to DC.

I'm just using typical 12V devices and lights.

Comment: You've basically answered your own question correctly.

Comment: This is what is done when delivering electricity around the country - the voltage is high, the current is low. So less power drops on the lines. Then it stepped down by transformer  substation near the consumer.

Comment: You keep the high current connections as short as possible.

Comment: In the most general terms, use high voltage for long runs and keep low voltage runs short. Whether it is AC or DC is not the key part. The key part is to move energy over long distance using high voltage. But in your case, AC means mains voltage and DC means 12V.

Comment: An alternative to DC-AC-DC conversion is to increase the voltage of the entire system. Many devices made for low voltage use also function at 24V or are available in a 24V version. By converting to 24V, power losses caused by wire resistance are only 1/4 of those at 12V. What distances do you want to cover?

Comment: But, if your load is low voltage DC, it may not be advantageous to use an inverter at all. I guess I would say it this way. If you are using an inverter anyway, it makes sense to put it near the panels and/or battery. But if you are adding an inverter to gain efficiency and reduce loss in the wires, it probably will not pay off for you. It would be simpler, more efficient, and less trouble in general to just use larger wires and forgo the inverter altogether.

Answer (score 3):

> AC is better on long distance.

It's not that AC on it's own is better. It's that the AC is higher voltage / lower current so that losses are less.

> So I was thinking converting to AC then just convert again to DC.

You might get better efficiency by stepping up to a higher voltage DC and stepping down again at the load.

Comment: Also AC is easier (aka i should say less expensive) to step up its voltage. Stepping DC voltage higher is harder, as I can remember :3

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios, it's easier when the AC is already generated and it's very efficient when done with a three-phase generator. The problem in this case is that the inverter to generate the AC won't be so efficient, hence the DC voltage booster suggestion. The DC-DC converter will use AC to boost but it will be 20 - 100 kHz and a much lighter transformer is required for that.

Comment: @Transistor AC is NOT better!I may sound like Tesla-hater but in DC we don't have the skin effect so the resistances are lower in a piece of wire.However one big advantage of the AC is the easier(much easier) stepping up to a higher voltage that is why we use it in transportation of electric power.

Comment: @Miss, I didn't say that AC was better. I was quoting the OP. I'm well aware of the pros and cons of AC versus DC power transmission but that was out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Power can be delivered at

1. Low Voltage with high current
2. High Voltage with low current

High current has higher losses in the resistance of the wire, so the High Voltage method will be more efficient for transmission long distances.
Some (or all) of this will be gain will be lost through the process of stepping up (inverter) and stepping down (power supply).
What will work best for you will depend of the load and distance. Some thicker copper cables may be a more cost effective solution.
The advantage of using a inverter and a PSU are that these are readily available off the shelf modules. Inverters can use a lot of power without supplying any load current, so this is the part to find a. its efficiency and b. its no load current. It would be good to use an inverter with a remote on/off control input and use this to turn the light on and off.

Answer (score 0):

An DC to AC converter requires at least 4 electronic switches + step up transformer, or LV DC to HV DC converter and then convert to AC, this is done in those alu boxes called 12VDC to 230VAC inverter.

Now the problem is that this is less efficient than having just a LV DC to HV DC converter which can use only one electronic switch and HF step up transformer or just an inductor. This is so called boost converter. For higher power a multi phase interleaved converter may be used.

On the other side a step down converter is needed. It could be a buck or flyback converter.

The use of AC as intermediate product makes no sense, since you could have problems with high capacitance of the long cable also.

Perhaps the simplest method for your case (just for LED lamps) is to use just a step up DC DC converter and then use ordinary LED lights 110/230VAC with built in SMPS. The el cheapo LED uses a capacitor divider, while a good LED has a rectifier and switcher. So the mains supply is rectified to DC (from 230VAC you get 325VDC) and then a step down DC DC converter is used.